# Armature Missing

Tags: rigging, armature

Was rigging my model and suddenly the armature disappeared.
Don't remember using weird shortcuts apart from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter/exit pose mode.

In the outliner it actually shows up as 'active' and 'visible' but cannot see it.
I'm using blender 2.82 The project does not come from older versions, it was created in this one. Already tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Found this: [Armature Disappeared](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80556/armature-disappeared)
but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was in isolate mode all the time.